# write dynamic formula in cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Range(A1).Value = "=SUM(Range(B1), Range(B1).Offset(xlToRight))"
```

I want to write a formula in a cell by using VBA, but I want to make it dynamic.
How can I write this code?
What I've tried is written above.

Comment: What is A1 and B1?

Comment: What's the actual formula you want and how is it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("B1").Value & "," & Range("B1").Offset(0, 1).Value & ")"`